# When a company requests your Cover Letter and Resume, can you just write the Cover Letter as the email body?

Tags: cover-letter

I don't remember sending a cover letter since Grade 11.

Every job I've ever gotten was because I wrote a nice short email that entices the hiring team to open the Resume to read it.

The company said "Attach your Resume AND Cover Letter". So then what can I put in the body of the email?

*I was excited to see a job posting which sounded just like my old jobs. I'd really appreciate it if you had a look at what I have to offer in the documents attached!*?

Answer (score 8):

#### Much better to attach it as a portable document than write it in text

- One, because that's literally mentioned in the email.
- Two, the resume and cover letter gets circulated within organizations via email and/or print. Making it into an attachment makes it easy to print, and that too with the formatting/legibility retained.

  Some organizations also have internal software/system which may require staff members to **attach** resume and cover letter. So, it becomes crucial that you share it in the form of a document than text.

You should consider attaching it in a portable format such as PDF (verses pages or document file), so that all the formatting, styling and hyperlinks are preserved. PDF is the most accessible format across any OS/platform, and is generally preferred by systems where a document is required to be uploaded.

Another benefit of PDF apart from retained formatting is that it couldn't be easily edited.

---

> So then what can I put in the body of the email?

As far as email body goes, keep it concise and to the point. Don't leave it empty.

> Hello Mr./Mrs. ,
>
> Please find attached my Cover Letter and Resume for the position of
> .
>
> Kindly let me know if any additional information is required. Thank
> you for considering my profile for the position.
>
> Regards
>
> Yours Truly